# Nuxt/Vue - How do you put a @blur in the vue-bootstrap-typeahead?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to trigger a function when I leave an input, but how I configured the input is by using `vue-bootstrap-typehead`. By inspecting the input element in the DOM it would be structured like this:

```html
<div id="myElement">
  <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
    <input type="search" autocomplete="off" class="form-control">
```

and this is my code:

```html
<vue-bootstrap-typeahead
   id="myElement"
   v-model="plateNumberFilter"
   :data="plateNumberOptions"
   size="sm"
   required
   @blur="myFunctionIsnnotTriggered"
   @hit="returnPlateNumberId()"
/>
```

I've tried adding the `id="myElement"` on the typeahead itself but it puts the `id` in the `div` instead, which kinda makes sense, but I would've wanted it to be in the `input` tag instead.

So I have 3 questions:

1. How do I add an @blur on the input of `vue-bootstrap-typeahead` component?
2. How do I add an `id` in the input of a `vue-bootstrap-typeahead` component?
3. How do I add an eventListener in the `input` tag inside the `vue-bootstrap-typeahead` component?

You don't need to answer 2 if you have an answer for 1 and so on. But it would be cool to have an answer to all 3 of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `vue-typeahead-component` [available events](https://github.com/alexurquhart/vue-bootstrap-typeahead#events) only include `hit` and `input` events, so you can't apply `@blur` to the component itself.

To add an event listener on the inner `<input>` of `vue-bootstrap-typeahead`:

1. Use a [template ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) on the `<vue-bootstrap-typeahead>` component.
2. From the ref, get its root DOM element via [`vm.$el`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-el).
3. Use [`Element.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) to get the inner `<input>`.
4. Use [`EventTarget.addEventListener('blur', handler)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to listen to the `blur` event on the `<input>`.

```html
<template>
  <vue-bootstrap-typeahead ref="typeahead" 1️⃣ />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async mounted() {
    await this.$nextTick()
    this.$refs.typeahead.$el 2️⃣
        .querySelector('input') 3️⃣
        .addEventListener('blur', (e) => console.log('blur', e)) 4️⃣
  },
}
</script>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-blur-listener-vue-bootstrap-typeahead?file=src/App.vue)